# Email using Python with Excel attachment

Tags: python, smtplib

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import smtplib,email,email.encoders,email.mime.text,email.mime.base
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email import encoders
from email.message import Message
from email.mime.audio import MIMEAudio
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
msg = MIMEMultipart()
# me == my email address
# you == recipient's email address
me = "sender@email.com"
you = "reciever@email.com "


# Create message container - the correct MIME type is multipart/alternative.
msg = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
msg['Subject'] = "msg"
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you

# Create the body of the message (a plain-text and an HTML version).
text = "Hi\nThis is text-only"
html = """\
<html> This is email</html>
"""

part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
#attach an excel file:
fp = open('TestStatus.xlsx', 'rb')
file1=email.mime.base.MIMEBase('application','vnd.ms-excel')
file1.set_payload(fp.read())
fp.close()
email.encoders.encode_base64(file1)
file1.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment;filename=anExcelFile.xlsx')

# Attach parts into message container.
# According to RFC 2046, the last part of a multipart message, in this case
# the HTML message, is best and preferred.
msg.attach(part2)
msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(file1)

composed = msg.as_string()

fp = open('msgtest.eml', 'w')
fp.write(composed)

# Credentials (if needed)  
# The actual mail send  
server = smtplib.SMTP('dc1smtp.com')  
server.starttls()  
server.sendmail(me, you, msg)  
server.quit()  
fp.close()



also when running it, I see this error message. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "excel.py", line 57, in <module>
server.sendmail(me, you, msg)
File "C:\Python33\lib\smtplib.py", line 775, in sendmail
(code, resp) = self.data(msg)
File "C:\Python33\lib\smtplib.py", line 516, in data
q = _quote_periods(msg)
File "C:\Python33\lib\smtplib.py", line 167, in _quote_periods
return re.sub(br'(?m)^\.', b'..', bindata)
File "C:\Python33\lib\re.py", line 170, in sub
return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

I have tested this code and it is working. the only problem i am having is that, when i run it, i dont recieve the emails that i am testing it with. But when i run this code. it creates a file named "msgtest.eml". This file is like a draft of my email or something. 
can someone show me how to use this show and be an actually email instead of a draft?
thanks

Comment: Are you sure you're ***sending the e-mail***? Check the last part of your code. :)

Comment: It would be more accurate to use the `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` content type. `application/vnd.ms-excel` is meant for `.xls` files (Excel 2003 and earlier).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[To send mail from localhost:](http://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtp-example)

```
import smtplib

me = "me@me.com"
you = "you@you.com"

# insert your code here
msg = ...

s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
s.sendmail(me, [to], msg.as_string())
```